# How to select a max value in a group in SQL

Tags: sql, max, drop-duplicates

My goal is to only have 1 row per part number/color combo. I tried using the max function however it doesn't seem to be working right, it will still give me duplicate values:
[image]

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

TRIM(PART_NO) AS PART_NO, 
TRIM(PART_CLR_CD) AS COLOR, 
MAX(EFCT_DT) AS EFCT_DT,
STD_CURRENCY,
STD_COST
    
FROM HSP.12

--where part_no like '181655MR A0%'

GROUP BY PART_NO,
PART_CLR_CD, 
STD_CURRENCY,
STD_COST
```

I am trying to select the most recent data per part. I have looked through other peoples concerns regarding MAX() in SQL but I cant find a solution that works for me. I only have 1 data source I am pulling from for more context. My table should look something like the image here
[image]

Comment: STD_COST is different for different dates, that's why your group by query is giving you duplicates. Do you want STD_COST in your output? If no, then don't select it and if yes, you cannot do it with max function.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two (or more) number/color combos having the same MAX EFCT_DT? Do you want all of them, or just one (which one?)?

Comment: Use a sub query to get the max date per part, join the base data to that on the part and max date.  1 row per part.  Alternatively if your RDBMS supports it, (we'd need to know RDBMS) one may be albe to use a table function such as lateral or cross apply to essentially run a quey returing the most recent dated record per part.  Look up lateral or cross apply with your RDBMS.

Comment: @jakbar My goal is to get the cost associated with the most recent date. I'm assuming I need to use a subquery per the reply from xQbert, how would I do that? I'm relatively new to using SQL. How would I know if my RDBMS supports with he is asking?

Comment: @BenjaminWang two asnwers provided both will work.  But without knowing the version of the database and the maker your're using, I can't say which one(s) will work. (mySQL? SQL Server 2020?) Oralce?) . .they both may.  and Jarlh's use over row_number is kinda the inbetween the old school and use of cross apply/lateral.

Comment: @xQbert If my RDBMS does support what you are asking, could you please provide and example of how to do what you are suggesting? I am still learning SQL.

Comment: @BenjaminWang already did in an answer below the comments  again row number used by jarlh should work as well provided it's supported.  The old school approach shoudl work on all RDBMS as far as I know regardless of how old the version in my opinion with a few exceptions  as far as efficienty, the row number is "better" if its supported by your system, and lateral/cross apply would yet be better especially if the date /part number is indexed on the table.  however all 3 design patterns will work.  Lateral/cross apply, row_number, or max and subquery.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I think you should try jarlh's solution being a newbie if you are using SQL server.

Comment: @xQbert If ROW_NUMBER() comes up as an unexpected token, does that mean I an running on something pre 2005? Would this help in finding a solution?

Comment: What does `select @@version;`, `select version();` or `select * from V$VERSION;` return?

Comment: @BenjaminWang  I wouldn't make that claim until we know what RDBMS and version you're using.  It's possible, it's possibe the RDBMS you're using doesn't support Row_number.  is it MsSQL? mySQL? Oralce? DB2? Presto? PostgreSQL? too many RDBMS to make that assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION` to get the row with highest EFCT_DT for each number/color combo.

```
select *
from
  (SELECT PART_NO, PART_CLR_CD AS COLOR, EFCT_DT, STD_CURRENCY, STD_COST
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by PART_NO, PART_CLR_CD order by EFCT_DT desc) rowno
   FROM HSP.12) dt
where rowno = 1
```

**Edit:** SQL-92 compliant answer - expected to work on any dbms:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(PART_NO) AS PART_NO, 
                TRIM(PART_CLR_CD) AS COLOR, 
                EFCT_DT,
                STD_CURRENCY,
                STD_COST
FROM HSP.12 h1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HSP.12 h2
                  WHERE h2.PART_NO = h1.PART_NO
                    AND h2.PART_CLR_CD = h1.PART_CLR_CD
                    AND h2.EFCT_DT > h1.EFCT_DT)
```

(`DISTINCT` is probably not needed.)

Comment: In terms of simplicity, I always like this solution for such scenarios.

Comment: Makes sense just depends on RDBMS.  Row_number has been supported for what 15+ years now... but who knows what RDBMS is being used.  Lateral / Cross apply are what 7-10 years old now...

Comment: I get the following error when trying to run the suggested BIC00004. DAL010059. An error occurred while accessing the database:
 An unexpected token "ROW_NUMBER" was found following "_CURRENCY, STD_COST
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.112
 Extended error description is: 
 An unexpected token "ROW_NUMBER" was found following "_CURRENCY, STD_COST
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".

Answer (score 2):

Table value functions Lateral or cross apply depending on RDMBS is the modern way of doing this.  The old school way of doing this was to use a query to get the max date per part and then inner join it to the base data set thereby giving you just max date per part record.

In the below the sub query aliased "Sub" does this and then joins back to your base set getting 1 record per part. (assuming date can't be repeated for a part)

```
SELECT
TRIM(PART_NO) AS PART_NO, 
TRIM(PART_CLR_CD) AS COLOR, 
EFCT_DT AS EFCT_DT,
STD_CURRENCY,
STD_COST
    
FROM HSP.12
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT MAX(EFCT_DT) maxDate, Part_No FROM HSP.12 GROUP BY Part_No) sub
 on sub.MaxDate = HSP.12.EFCT_DT 
and sub.Part_No = HSP.12.Part_No
--where part_no like '181655MR A0%'
```